# Can I use 'such.. that' and 'such.. where' this way?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Let's look at the sentence.

> He is such a bad person whom no one wants to talk to.

Is the sentence grammatically correct? If it's correct, can I rewrite the sentence as:
*He is such a bad person that no one wants to talk to*.
One more sentence is:

> This is such a place where everyone wants to live.

Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not idiomatic, but your alternative version is almost correct.

> He is such a bad person that no-one wants to talk to *him.*

Similarly, your second sentence should be **either :**

> This is such a nice* place that everyone wants to live here.

*or any synonym of 'nice'.

**or:**

> This is the kind of place that everyone wants to live in.

Comment: Let's say a man named Ram teases girls. Now if I say "Ram is a bad person and I don't like *such* people" will it be correct? So I use 'such' in this sense. Then why can't I say "This is such a place where everyone wants to live"? I'm confused.

Comment: That particular usage of _such_ is very old-fashioned. Through Google Ngrams I found this, describing Rochester, Kent in the 1790s: _The bishop never resides there, for although there nominally is a palace , it is such a place as is not fit for the reception of any private gentleman._ Nowadays we would say _it is the kind of place_.